# Massive size difference between 32 and 64bit libraries

Tags: gcc, 32bit-64bit, glibc, configure

I have been building some linux libraries in 32bit and I intent to build many more.

However the size of the built 32bit libraries is MUCH smaller than their 64bit counterparts.

For instance, the 32bit libpng12.so.0.14.0 uses only 203KB, against 513KB of the 64bit version.

32bit libfreetype.so.6.3 occupies 595KB, against 1.9MB of the 64bit!

From the few 32 bit libraries, the only exception is glibc, were 32bit libraries uses much more space. For instance, ld-2.18.so uses 156KB, against 669KB of ld-2.17.so (yes, I realize its not the same version, but difference hsouldn't be that big)

Obviously, this difference is not without cause. I used a quite different process to build the "generic" 32bit libraries when compared to glibc

for generic it is:

```
CFLAGS (or CPPFLAGS)=-m32 ./configure --prefix=/... --host=i686-gnu-linux
```

while for glibc it was:

```
CC="gcc -m32 -march=core2 -mtune=core2 -O2" CXX="g++ -m32 -march=core2 -mtune=core2 -O2" ../configure --prefix=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux-32bit/Glibc-2.17/ --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=i686-gnu-linux --enable-kernel-2.6.32 --enable-profile
```

for 64bit glibc it was:

```
CFLAGS="-march=core2 -mtune=core2 -O2" ../configure --prefix=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glibc-2.18/ --enable-kernel=2.6.32 --enable-profile
```

So, my fear is that none of the generic 32bit libraries were build correctly and so, will crash 32bit software that will try to use them. Perhaps 32bit glibc is also problematic.

I tried to run a 32bit hello-world with:

```
./ld-linux.so.2 --library-path /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Gcc-4.9.4/lib32/ /home/leopoldo/Desktop/test-32bit
```

and it crashed with a seg fault error. Since this is GLibc, I ma not sure this indicates some error or some conflict with auxiliary 64bit libraries being used instead of 32bit

But how I can know by sure? What tests can I do? I am even more concerned with the "generic" 32bit. I don't waste time building dozens of them to them be forced to throw them in the garbage and have to start everything over again.

P.S: Besides being using a custom built Glibc, I am also using a custom built GCC, that I compiled with:

```
../configure --prefix=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Gcc-4.9.4 --disable-checking --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-multiarch --enable-multlib --with-multilib-list=m32,m64 --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu

make -j2 BOOT_CFLAGS='-O' bootstrap
```

After installing it on its own dir, I renamed the system libstdc++.so.6.0.13, adding a "bak" extension to it, removed the libstdc++.so.6 sym link to it, and created a new one pointing to the libstdc++.so.6.0.20 that it is on Gcc's own dir.

Comment: Use the `size` utility to investigate the actual sizes of the code and data areas of the objects, not the raw file size.

Comment: @Kaz Hi. Some results:  text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 195527    1628      48  197203   30253 libpng.so.3.14.0 (32bit)

Comment: text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 149028    1800      16  150844   24d3c libpng12.so.0.14.0 (64bi)

Comment: text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 536023   12076       8  548107   85d0b libfreetype.so.6.3.10

Comment: text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 455334   18752      16  474102   73bf6 libfreetype.so.6.3.10 (64bt)

Comment: text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 185960    1144      48  187152   2db10 libpng12.so.0.14.0 (32bit)

Comment: text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 162391    2760      16  165167   2852f libpng.so.3.14.0 (64bit)

Comment: OK; so these sizes are clearly indicating that the 64 bit executables have significantly **smaller** code sizes. The initialized static data areas are bigger (but are not large in absolute size for these files, so they make little difference).   The bloat you are seeing is elsewhere, like debug symbols or something; try running `strip` on the files.

Comment: @Kaz Hi. I did "strip -v libfreetype.so.6.3.10" for the 32 and 64bit version. Then executed "size libfreetype.so.6.3.10" on both again. It didn't change their filesize. Is that that I was supposed to do?

Comment: Right; after `strip`, we hope that the raw file size will change. The `size` utility will report the same numbers. Stripping an executable/lib does not change the amount of code, or static initialized or zero-initialized data in the file, but may trim the file by removing debug symbols and related info.

Comment: @Kaz. Right, but since size didn't change, what can I learn about it? The purpose of all this is to check if the 32bit libraries are working as intended or if they are broken.

Comment: If that's the purpose, then probably the `size` info should assure you that the 32 bit libraries are not massively smaller in the main payload content: they have more bytes of code, and a little fewer bytes of initialized data, but are in a similar ballpark.  Running `strip` on both the 64 and 32 bit libraries could level out some of the file size difference to confirm that. `strip` won't remove anything to use the library, just debugging.

Comment: @Kaz, Apparently there was a mistake in the values that I informed after using strip in the libraries. I checked the values again and now they are much closer, with the 32bit ones always being somewhat smaller. Is there a case where the debug information might be useful? Like building another libraries that depends on these striped? I ask because I am seriously thinking about applying strip to all the libraries, as the size diminishes greatly. libasound went from 4MB to 916KB

Comment: No, debug info is only needed for things symbolically debugging with GDB, and resolving backtrace symbols. A common practice in embedded systems is to strip everything that is installed on the target. The binaries with debug info are retained as separate package that can be installed on a case by case basis. Remote debugging is also a thing: the target has only stripped binaries; the remote debugger has the debug info.